# Perl: Program Crashing Upon Creation of a Hash

Tags: perl, hash, crash

As a follow up to a question asked earlier, I am creating a hash with keys between a user specified range, also with a specified increment size ($binsize). The code to create this hash seems to be correct:

```
my %hash;
for (my $increm = $lowerbound; $increm <= $upperbound; ++$binsize) {

        $hash{$increm} = 0;

}
```

with default variable values:

```
$lowerbound = 1000
$upperbound = 1500
$binsize = 1
```

But when I go to print the keys of the hash using:

```
print "$_\n" for keys %hash;
```

The program does not perform the operation and crashes. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: The aim is eventually to turn the completed hash into a CSV, so if I cannot view the hash at this stage, how can I check if the keys are populated correctly?

PROBLEM FIXED NOW:

changing:

```
for (my $increm = $lowerbound; $increm <= $upperbound; ++$binsize) {
```

to:

```
for (my $increm = $lowerbound; $increm <= $upperbound; $increm+=$binsize) {
```

seemed to fix the problem

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see what's wrong with this statement? `My car didn't start. What is the problem?` Be specific when describing your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (my $increm = $lowerbound; $increm <= $upperbound; ++$binsize) {
```

`$increm` doesnt change value so this `for` loop is endless

Maybe you wanted this:

```
for (my $increm = $lowerbound; $increm <= $upperbound; $increm++) {
```

**Edit:**

If you want to increment `$increm` by the value of `$binsize`:

```
foreach (my $increm = $lowerbound; $increm <= $upperbound; $increm += $binsize) {
```

Comment: I need $increm to increase by the value of $binsize each time round the loop starting at $lowerbound and stopping at $upperbound, I'm not this this fixes the problem.

Comment: Just tried that a few minutes ago :p thanks for your suggestion anyway!